# GParted won't let me edit a partition

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, gparted

I have this 72 GB hard disk that I installed Ubuntu 14.02 LTS 64 bit on. Now, I want to split it and leave 50 GBs for Ubuntu and install in the to-be-created partition the server version of the OS.

The issue at hand is that GParted won't let me change the size of the partition I want to shrink. It reads : minimum size = 72222 mb , maximum size = 7222 mb and obviously doesn't allow me to edit the partition.

Comment: Have you unmounted the disk? The only way to edit the partition is unmount the disk.

Comment: Are you trying on mounted disk?!

Comment: I do mot know how to unmount a disk. Could you tell me a bit about that?

Comment: You can also install gparted to a pen drive and run it from the pendrive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, you can not work with mounted partitions. Since you are trying to modify the partition on which Ubuntu is installed, you can't do this from your installed OS as you cant unmount the partition. So what you have to do is:

1. Create a live USB/DVD and boot into Ubuntu Live
2. In Gparted you start from the live environment, unmount the partition. If the partition is mounted, 'key' icon will be present next to the name of the partition. To unmount from Gparted, just right click on the partition and click `Unmount`.
   [image]
3. Now modify the partition.
4. Reboot and Voilà! It's done.

Comment: So should I use the USB I installed it with, boot into try without installing, getting gparted in that mode and simply modify it from there?

Comment: @WordLegio, exactly! Just don't forget to unmount your partition.

Comment: I'll try it asap! Thank you dear sir *flips fedora*